# Enable and disable button when text is entered in textInput or removed in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to make button enabled when something is typed in text field and it should get disabled when value in the text field is removed.

But currently when i type in the text field the the button gets activated but when i remove the text it remains enabled and doesn't update it's state.

What should i do?

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableHighlight,TextInput,TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground,Button } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";


class App extends Component {

  state={
    username:'',
    password:'',
    validity:true
  }

  static navigationOptions={
    header:null
  };
render() {
    return (

     <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={{marginLeft:50,marginTop:30}}>
       <TextInput 
         style={styles.textInputStyle}
         placeholderTextColor="#FFF" 
         placeholder='Username'
         onChangeText={(value)=>this.setState({username:value,validity:false})}
         value={this.state.username}
          />
       <TextInput 
         style={styles.textInputStyle}
         placeholderTextColor="#FFF" 
         placeholder='Password'
         secureTextEntry={true}
         onChangeText={(value)=>this.setState({password:value,validity:false})}
         value={this.state.password}
          />
       </View>

       <View style={{alignSelf:'center'}} >

        <TouchableOpacity style={this.state.validity? 
             styles.inactiveStyle:styles.activeStyle}                           
             disabled={this.state.validity}                                                                                                                     
             onPress={this.handleLogin}>
         <Text>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: App,    
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    defaultNavigationOptions:{
      header:null
    }
  }
);
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,    
  },
  textInputStyle:{
    height:50,
    width:300,
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderBottomColor:'#FFF',
    marginTop:20,
    color:'#FFF'
  },
  activeStyle:{
    marginTop:18,
    width:180,
    backgroundColor:'#05acfa', 
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10
  },
  inactiveStyle:{
    marginTop:18,
    width:180,
    backgroundColor:'grey', 
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Answer (score 3):

If we talking about disable in case when one of field is empty better change disable prop logic. So you don't need additional variable, and logic will be clear

```
disabled={!Boolean(this.state.username && this.state.password)}
```

so if any of field is empty you will get true

in your case

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableHighlight,TextInput,TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground,Button } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";


class App extends Component {

  state={
    username:'',
    password:'',
    validity:true
  }

  static navigationOptions={
    header:null
  };
render() {
    return (

     <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={{marginLeft:50,marginTop:30}}>
       <TextInput 
         style={styles.textInputStyle}
         placeholderTextColor="#FFF" 
         placeholder='Username'
         onChangeText={(value)=>this.setState({username:value,validity:false})}
         value={this.state.username}
          />
       <TextInput 
         style={styles.textInputStyle}
         placeholderTextColor="#FFF" 
         placeholder='Password'
         secureTextEntry={true}
         onChangeText={(value)=>this.setState({password:value,validity:false})}
         value={this.state.password}
          />
       </View>

       <View style={{alignSelf:'center'}} >

        <TouchableOpacity style={this.state.validity? 
             styles.inactiveStyle:styles.activeStyle}                           
             disabled={!Boolean(this.state.username && this.state.password)}                                                                                                                     
             onPress={this.handleLogin}>
         <Text>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: App,    
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    defaultNavigationOptions:{
      header:null
    }
  }
);
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,    
  },
  textInputStyle:{
    height:50,
    width:300,
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderBottomColor:'#FFF',
    marginTop:20,
    color:'#FFF'
  },
  activeStyle:{
    marginTop:18,
    width:180,
    backgroundColor:'#05acfa', 
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10
  },
  inactiveStyle:{
    marginTop:18,
    width:180,
    backgroundColor:'grey', 
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: it enables the button ones text is entered but does not disable it ones the text is removed. It does not updates the state of validity ones text is removed from the field.

Comment: Sorry, my fault I forgot wrap value, try `disabled={!Boolean(this.state.username && this.state.password)}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the button to be disabled when the value is an empty string. In your onChangeText callback check if the value is "" and then update the state to disable the button.

```
onChangeText={(value) => {
if (value === "")
   this.setState({password:value, validity:true})}
else 
   this.setState({password:value, validity:false})}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update the state of disabled in your TouchableOpacity component. See [here](https://reactnativecode.com/disabled-button-state/)

Comment: yeah i have done that only the solution provided by @Roman Akash was helpful and it's working.